# wash shows nothing

Tags: aircrack-ng

`wash -i mon0` shows nothing. I'v created /etc/reaver directory, downgraded libpcap to 1.4.0-2 version. My workflow is the following:

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 down
iwconfig wlp3s0 mode monitor 
ifconfig wlp3s0 up 
ifconfig 
airmon-ng check wlp3s0 
kill 985 1145 2450 
airmon-ng check wlp3s0 
airmon-ng start wlp3s0 
airodump-ng mon0
wash -i mon0
```

Still wash shows nothing...

`airodump-ng mon0` shows two APs.

`sudo lsof | grep wash` shows:
[image: sudo lsof | grep wash]

`uname -ra` output:

```
Linux andy-Aspire-E5-571G 4.15.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 18:03:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Maybe my routers aren't just vulnerable to WPS attack? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgarded my system from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.1, reinstalled some packets and now everything works fine.